How can I get a pipe to *completely* stop if a command fails?
I was using this code to use jq to format a json file in place
jq . foo.json | sponge foo.json

It works great, but has one fatal flaw - if jq . foo.json fails (due to, say, a parsing error), the pipe just keeps on tickin and writes nothing to foo.json, wiping the file.
The behavior I want is something that is the same as foo | bar, but if foo fails, bar will not be executed. set -o pipefail seemed promising, but it turns out that's not what it does. This feels like a common enough use case that there would be some clever shorthand for it, but I can't figure it out.
Requested example json data:
I want
   "foo"

to be turned into
"foo"

and
"foo

to be left alone, whereas my program will wipe the file.

In jq ... | sponge > foo.json the shell starts jq and sponge simultaneously. If it didn't then sponge wouldn't be running while jq is producing output. So, are you asking how to stop sponge when jq stops (I'd expect that to happen by default) or how to make sponge wait until jq has stopped (you don't know if jq will fail or not before it completes running) before sponge starts to write to foo.json (if so, don't use a pipe) or something else?

@EdMorton Interesting, I guess I fundamentally misunderstood how pipes worked. I guess in that context what I'm asking for doesn't really makes sense.

Can you share the json file?
You could try this.
jq . foo.json > temp.json && mv temp.json foo.json
This will first run jq . foo.json > temp.json.
If jq succeeds, it will move temp.json to foo.json, overwriting it with the formatted JSON.
If jq fails, temp.json won't be updated, and foo.json will remain unchanged.
Update:
if jq . foo.json > foo.json.tmp && mv foo.json.tmp foo.json; then
    echo "JSON formatted successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to format JSON"
    rm -f foo.json.tmp
fi

Or you could try this, it will write the output to dev/null instead of creating a file.
jq . foo.json > foo.json.tmp 2>/dev/null && mv foo.json.tmp foo.json

If you want to try the try/catch function from jq I think it would go something like this.
jq 'try . catch empty' foo.json > foo.json.tmp 2>/dev/null && mv foo.json.tmp foo.json

I tried both    "foo" and "foo with the codes above and they all change    "foo" to "foo" or leave "foo alone.

Any json file will do, just remove a quote from something and my command will wipe the file. Your answer does work, and I would consider it an improvement in that regard, but there are two things I'm not really satisfied with. 1 - it requires me to write the name of an intermediate file. This is just aesthetic I suppose, but the bigger problem is 2 - in the event of a failure, I pollute the directory with a temp.json. I suppose the solution to 2, is to add rm -f temp.json to the end of the command. And I guess that's what I'll do if there really isn't anything better.

i updated my code with the rm -f option and added another method as well.. let me know if it works

I would love it if there was a more concise way that didn't require an intermediate file, but in the case that there is not, I will award this the answer.

@Mason i added 2 other methods, 1 writes to dev/null and the other tries to use the trycatch method in jq.

Another way could be this (adapted after tripleee's comment): do not use sponge, but before writing to file check jq exit code:
if result=$(jq . foo.json); then
    echo "$result" > foo.json
else
    echo "There was an error. Exiting now."
    exit 1
fi


Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern? You can combine the assignment into the if statement; if result=$(jq ...); then

@tripleee you are right :-)
